# Are multiple responses legal in HTTP?

Tags: http, publish-subscribe, chunked-encoding

I'm a bit rusty on nuances of the HTTP protocol and I'm wondering if it can support publish/subscribe directly?

HTTP is a request reponse protocol. So client sends a request and the server sends back a response.
In HTTP 1.0 a new connection was made for each request.
Now HTTP 1.1 improved on HTTP 1.0 by allowing the client to keep the connection open and make multiple requests.

I realise you can upgrade an HTTP connection to a websocket for fast 2 way communications. What I'm curious about is whether this is strictly necessary?

For example if I request a resource "http://somewhere.com/fetch/me/slowly"

Is the server free to reply directly twice?
Such as first with a 202 accepted
and then shortly later with the content when it is ready, 
but without the client sending an additional request first?

i.e.

```
Client: GET http://somewhere.com/fetch/me/slowly
Server: 202 "please wait..."
Server: 200 "here's your document"
```

Would it be correct to implement a publish/subscribe service this way?
For example:

```
Client: http://somewhere.com/subscribe
Server: item 1
...
Server: item 2
```

I get the impression that this 'might' work because clients will typically have an event loop watching the connection but is technically wrong (because a client following the protocol need not be implemented that way).

However, if you use [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) this would work.

HTTP/2 seems to allow this as well but I'm not clear whether something changed to make it possible.

I haven't seen much discussion of this in relation to pub/sub so what if anything is wrong with using plain HTTP/1.1 with or without chunked encoding?

If this works why do you need things like RSS or ATOM?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A HTTP request can have multiple 'responses', but all responses except the final have statuscodes in the `1xx` range, such as [102 Processing](https://evertpot.com/http/102-processing).

However, these responses are only headers, never bodies.

HTTP/1.1 (like 1.0 before it) is a [request/response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) protocol. Sending a response unsolicited is not allowed. HTTP/2 is a frames protocol which adds [server push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push) which allows the server to  offer extra data and handle multiple requests in parallel but doesn't change its request/response nature.

It is possible to keep a HTTP connection open and keep sending more data though. Many (audio, video) streaming services will use this.

However, this just looks like a continuous body that keeps on streaming, rather than many multiple HTTP responses.

> If this works why do you need things like RSS or ATOM

Because keeping a TCP connection open is not free.

Comment: I think I could accept this answer with a minor tweak. I'll try doing it myself and you can correct as appropriate.

Comment: I've attempted the edit but I'm not entirely satisfied with my failure to define a "frames protocol".

Comment: @BruceAdams i kinda disagree with your edit and I don't think using HTTP/2 push is an appropriate use for this. HTTP/2 is really just for optimistically populating caches. It should not be used as a pub/sub-like system.

Comment: Yes. That was badly phrased "but doesn't change its request/response nature" is insufficient.

Comment: @Evert "but the responses all have statuscodes in the 1xx range", where do that information came from? I dont disagree, I just want to find some official source.

Comment: @wair92 read the RFCs!

Comment: What about [103 Early Hints](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#early-hints)? In the examples given, the subsequent responses have 2xx and 3xx codes.

Comment: @chharvey I didn't write this clearly, but there's always one final non-1xx response, which is the _real_ status code.