# Send updates about the state of a running HTTP request to the client

Tags: node.js, http, request

I would like to send updates of a running HTTP request to the client to tell it at what stage the request-triggered process currently is.

The process behind the request does currently the following things (in this order):

Client-side:

- Client sends an HTTP Request (upload of a file) to the server

Server-side:

- Takes the uploaded file
- Encrypt it
- Upload it to an archive storage
- Return response to the client
  (Meanwhile, the client does not know what currently happens)

Client-side:

- Get response and show it to the user

I want to tell the client at what stage the process is, like “Uploading done. Encrypting…” and so on.

Is there a way to realize that, or am I missing something? Is it even possible to do?

Frameworks I'm using:

- Client: Next.js
- Server: Hapi.dev for API development

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send multiple responses while computing in Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729360/how-to-send-multiple-responses-while-computing-in-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can send non-final 1xx header responses for your http request as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53231701/7179628).

Comment: I would like to send detailed responses, especially when I need information about the uploaded file(s).